# Nodejs express posting query via jquery/ajax can't set headers error while reading response

Tags: jquery, node.js, ajax, express

I am trying to read responses from my server after posting a query via jQuery and Ajax. I think it's because I am trying to render the page using `res.render` and writing out a response after receiving data from my db using `res.end`. But I don't know how to resolve it as I am a newbie to NodeJS express.

Here is my nodejs part that receives the request, queries the db and tries to send the response:

```
app.all('/Search', function(req, res) {
    res.render('search');
    var query = req.body.username;
    if (req.body.username)
    {
    db.collection('users').find({username: query}).toArray(function(err, result) {
        if (err) return console.log(err);
        console.log("Request body  = "+req.body.username);
        console.log(result);
        res.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }); 
        res.end(JSON.stringify(data));
    });
    }
});
```

Here is the `search.ejs` html page with the jquery embedded in it:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>MY APP</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div style="margin: 0 auto;width: 500px;">
        <form id="searchForm" action="/Search" method="post" style="margin: 0 auto; width: 200px; margin-top: 100px;">
        <input id="username" type="text" placeholder="Search" name="username"  style="margin: 20px auto; font-size: 50px;">
        <!-- <input type="file" name="picture"> -->
        <button type="submit"  style="margin: 20px auto; font-size: 50px;">Submit</button>
        </form>
    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
     $('#searchForm').on('submit', function (event) {
         console.log("HI");
         event.preventDefault(); // Stop the form from causing a page refresh.
         var data = {
         username: $('#username').val()
         };
         console.log("DATA === "+data);
         $.ajax({
         url: 'http://localhost:3000/Search',
         data: data,
         method: 'POST'
         }).then(function (response) {
         console.log("Response ="+response);
         // Do stuff with the response, like add it to the page dynamically.
             $('body').append(response);
         }).catch(function (err) {
         console.error(err);
         });
     });
    </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

And here is the output in the terminal:

```
Server started at port:3000
Request body  = abc
[ { _id: 5938c2f9453e40053965e9ec,
    username: 'abc',
    specialty: 'dsfsaddfjk',
    address: 'oidjfioa' } ]
/home/vineet/Desktop/serene-brushlands-55292/node_modules/mongodb/lib/utils.js:123
    process.nextTick(function() { throw err; });
                                  ^
```

> Error: Can't set headers after they are sent.

```
    at ServerResponse.setHeader (_http_outgoing.js:371:11)
    at ServerResponse.writeHead (_http_server.js:183:21)
    at /home/vineet/Desktop/serene-brushlands-55292/app.js:52:10
    at handleCallback (/home/vineet/Desktop/serene-brushlands-55292/node_modules/mongodb/lib/utils.js:120:56)
    at /home/vineet/Desktop/serene-brushlands-55292/node_modules/mongodb/lib/cursor.js:860:16
    at handleCallback (/home/vineet/Desktop/serene-brushlands-55292/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/cursor.js:171:5)
    at setCursorDeadAndNotified (/home/vineet/Desktop/serene-brushlands-55292/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/cursor.js:505:3)
    at nextFunction (/home/vineet/Desktop/serene-brushlands-55292/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/cursor.js:651:7)
    at Cursor.next [as _next] (/home/vineet/Desktop/serene-brushlands-55292/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/cursor.js:692:3)
    at fetchDocs (/home/vineet/Desktop/serene-brushlands-55292/node_modules/mongodb/lib/cursor.js:856:10)
    at /home/vineet/Desktop/serene-brushlands-55292/node_modules/mongodb/lib/cursor.js:879:7
    at handleCallback (/home/vineet/Desktop/serene-brushlands-55292/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/cursor.js:171:5)
    at nextFunction (/home/vineet/Desktop/serene-brushlands-55292/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/cursor.js:682:5)
    at /home/vineet/Desktop/serene-brushlands-55292/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/cursor.js:593:7
    at queryCallback (/home/vineet/Desktop/serene-brushlands-55292/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/cursor.js:232:18)
    at /home/vineet/Desktop/serene-brushlands-55292/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/connection/pool.js:469:18
```

The response that I receive in the jQuery stub is the html for `search.ejs` itself. Please help!!

Comment: you can't res.render() and then send a json response.. that doesn't make any sense. Either return json or return html/whatever render does. not both.

Comment: But I need to render the page as that is where I get the input data from. How can I go about doing both?

Comment: What about it doesn't make sense to you? I need to view the page `search.ejs`, then on that page enter a username to search, which is searched in the database (mlab), and display all the details for that username on the same page, which I am trying to do via ajax/jquery.

Comment: You can't return both a page and a json response via a single ajax request. Asking how to do so doesn't make sense.

Comment: But that is what the problem is. I don't want the page in the ajax request response. Just the json response.

Comment: I've clearly stated in the question that I am a newbie to nodejs. So I don't know all the details of everything I am using here.

Comment: render essentially calls `res.end('<thehtmlforthepagerenderedhere />')`.

Comment: Ok so any suggestions on resolving this issue?

Comment: don't call render.

Comment: If i don't call render, `search.ejs` doesn't get loaded in the first place. that's what I've been trying to tell you mate.

Comment: That shouldn't be related to this request. Do you possibly need two different routes? You shouldn't have a route that returns either json or html.

Comment: How is it not related to this request?? The input form where I collect the data for this request lies in `search.ejs`. If `search.ejs` doesn't load, I have no request to work with!!

Comment: it makes no sense to both have res.render and res.end(jsonstring). there's  clearly a logic error here. You can't do both. No situation will *need* both because having both is simply invalid. not an option.

Comment: Ok so could you please show an example of what you would do for what I am trying to do here?

Comment: I still don't fully understand what you are *trying* to do. It looks like you're trying to plug in an ajax request in place of a form submit and expect it to "just work". the ajax request isn't going to know how to convert your json string back into the html format that your page expects, you would have to add more logic to accomplish that. To me it looks like you would be better served by not using ajax yet. You seem to be treating this as if it were php.

Comment: Ok. I think I understand what is confusing you. The part where the ajax request tries to place the response back in the page is not my main concern. My main concern is simply taking the data from the input form on the page. Query the data in the database. And send the result of that query back through `res.someMethod()`. I will format the html for the ajax later. First I need my nodejs express part to work.

Comment: Right. but the node.js express part won't work if you're both trying to respond with json AND html. you can't do that. Which do you want? JSON or HTML? Looking at your client-side code, you may be better served by returning HTML.

Comment: Yes I would like to return html.

Comment: Then you'll need your render() to do that. read .ejs docs.

Comment: alright. Could you please tell me how I could do that with render? I know nothing about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer myself. Turned the `app.all` to `app.post` and added another `app.get` to `Search` and moved the render to it.